Is this the correct cellular chain complex for a (2n)-gon?
This question is from a publicly available practice qualifying exam (Stanford geometry and topology), which I am using to help learn this field. I misunderstood the question a few days ago and tried to perform the computation via simplicial homology. I deleted the question and redid it after rereading through Hatcher's chapter on homology.
I want to check and make sure that I properly answered part (a).

For $n \ge 2$, let $X_n$ be the space obtained from a regular $(2n)$-gon by identifying the opposite sides with parallel orientations. For example, $X_3$ is

The above description produces a cell decomposition of $X_n$
(a) Write down the associated cellular chain complex.

Answer part (a):
Examine the fundamental polygon.
Take the cellular chain group corresponding to $C_0$ to be in powers of one generator.
Take the cellular chain group corresponding to $C_1$ to have $n$ generators, and take the cellular chain group corresponding to $C_2$ to have one generator. Then our cellular chain complex takes the form
$$ \boxed{ \; 0 \rightarrow \mathbb Z \xrightarrow{d_2} \mathbb Z^n \xrightarrow{d_1} \mathbb Z \rightarrow 0 \;}$$
Would this be correct?

To write down a chain complex is to specify the chain groups and the boundary maps. You've named the maps, but you haven't actually specified what happens to the generators of $C_2$ and $C_1$.

@TabesBridges $d_1$ would be the zero map and $d_2$ would also send all elements to zero because of the fundamental word, right? If so I'll add it into the question.

Before writing down chain complexes, ask yourself: What are the dimensions of the chain groups?

@LeeMosher
#(0-cells)  = 1  ,
#(1-cells) = n  ,
#(2-cells) = 1

Why is there only one vertex?

@JohnPalmieri Yes, that's what I found most challenging and nebulous in the question (as well as in Hatcher's section on cellular homology, which I've read and tried to understand several times). I thought initially you could put at most 2 vertices on it for $n \ge 3$ (but only one vertext for n= 2) . Given a comment on my old question I thought the answer would be 1. If you can answer that I'm "wrong" and explain how to find the number of 0-cells, I'll mark you as the answer.

If $Y_n$ is the $2n$-gon with no identifications, then it has $2n$ vertices, $2n$ edges, and one $2$-cell. After doing the gluing to get $X_n$, there is still one $2$-cell, and since the edges are identified in pairs, there are $n$ edges. The boundary of the $2$-cell is zero, since  each edge appears twice in the boundary but with opposite orientations — once clockwise and once counterclockwise, so they cancel.
Now for the vertices: you need to look at the gluing to see how they are identified. If $n=2$, you have a square with opposite edges identified. The lower left corner is identified with the upper left corner, since both are the “starting point” of the horizontal edge. Similarly, the lower left corner is identified with the lower right corner, since they are both the sources of the vertical edge. Finally, the lower right is glued to the upper right. This means that all of the vertices are glued together: there is a single vertex. Each edge starts and ends at that vertex $v$, so the boundary of each edge is $v-v=0$.
When $n=3$, we have the picture in the question. A similar analysis should show that there are $2$ vertices after the gluing, not just one. If we call them $v$ and $w$, then each edge goes from $v$ to $w$ or from $w$ to $v$.
Now what happens in the general case? Choose one vertex and label it $v$. Its mirror image will also be $v$. Note that there are $n-2$ vertices between these two. I claim that if you organize the work well, you should find that as you go around the polygon, every other vertex will end up identified, so if $n$ is even, you will end up with every vertex identified with $v$, while if $n$ is odd, there will be two equivalence classes of vertices. Try out the next few cases to see the pattern, and then you should be able to write down a careful proof.
